# Create basic field data in template like node for custom entities {{ custom_entity.id }}

Tags: nodes, 9

I see node preprocess does this

`$variables['node'] = $variables['elements']['#node'];`

and then in the template one can do this

`{{ node.id }}`

but when I create a custom entity and do the same,  I never get past all the the errors like

```
Exception: Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 476 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php).
```

What are they doing special for node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does `{{ custom_entity.id }}` produce this error message?**

> Exception: Object of type Drupal\Core\Field\FieldItemList cannot be
> printed.

If your entity defines `id` for the entity ID then `{{ custom_entity.id }}` is ambiguous. It can mean the object property (the ID field) or the method [EntityInterface::id()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityInterface.php/function/EntityInterface%3A%3Aid/9.1.x).

So use parentheses to make it clear it is a method:

```
{{ custom_entity.id() }}
```

Or retrieve the field value when you have already a field as the error message shows:

```
{{ custom_entity.id.value }}
```

---

**What are they doing special for node?**

The node entity is using `nid` as ID field, so `id` and `nid` are unambigious.

Method `id()`:

```
{{ node.id }}
```

Field `nid`:

```
{{ node.nid.value }}
```

Comment: So for node here
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.2.x/core/modules/node/node.module#L482

and here

https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.2.x/core/modules/node/templates/node.html.twig#L9

why can't my custom entity do this exact same thing?

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem implementing the same thing as in nodes. You only have to be careful about the Twig abstraction layer for PHP objects to avoid the error message.